# Error: Invalid column name 'is_memory_optimized' when expand tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am encountering an error message when I try to expand or refresh tables in SQL Server. Since I cannot upload images, I will describe below. Could anyone help me?

I am using SQL Server 2014 CTP1

Failed to retrieve data for this request.(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

**Additional information:** 
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-
SQL statement or batch.
(Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

Invalid column name 'is_memory_optimized'.

Invalid column name 'is_memory_optimized'.(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 207)

Screenshot:

[Image http://tinypic.com/r/6p6iap/8](http://tinypic.com/r/6p6iap/8)

Comment: Why are you still using CTP1?

Comment: You can upload your screenshots to a free image hosting, e.g. tinypic.com, and post a link here.....

Comment: @JodyT I installed this long time ago.

Comment: @kzhang12 Are you also using the SSMS version from SQL Server 2014 CTP1, or did you upgrade that (or some component it uses) to the final SQL Server 2014 version? I ask because this looks like it could well be caused by some weird and completely unsupported mix of versions.

Comment: @hvd Thanks for asking. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled the CTP1, and installed the final SQL Server 2014 version. Problem solved. Thanks everyone.